# Hide/Show field base on drop down in PHP while loop with JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have data array in PHP foreach loop, And every set of data (`tr`) I have a dropdown field which I named it `brand_new[]`, this drop down field will show/hide my `account_no` field which is temporarily hidden because of `style='display:none'`, When the user selects `brand_new` the `account_no` field will hide, when user selects `repo` the  `account_no` will show.

This is what I've done so far.

**PHP**

```
  foreach ($result as $r) {
      echo "<tr>
               <td align='center'>$r->model</td>    
               <td align='center'>$r->color</td>
               <td align='center'>$r->engine_no</td>
               <td align='center'>$r->chassis_no</td>
               <td align='center'>                   
                  <select class='new' name='brand_new[]'>
                    <option>Choose</option>
                    <option value='brand_new'>Brand New</option>
                    <option value='repo'>Repo</option>
                    </select> 
                 </td>
               <td> 
                 <div id='repo' class='search_item' style='display:none'>    
                        <input type='text' name='account_no' required> 
                     </div>
                </td>

             </tr>
         ";
       }
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {

    // Search by dates function
    var search = $('.new')

    search.change(function() {
        $('.search_item').hide()
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show() 

    });

  });

</script>
```

**View page source**

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center"><h4>Model</h4></th>
        <th class="text-center"><h4>Color</h4></th>
        <th class="text-center"><h4>Engine Number</h4></th>
        <th class="text-center"><h4>Chassis Number</h4></th>
        <th class="text-center"><h4>Brand New</h4></th>
        <th class="text-center"><h4>Account No. (repo)</h4></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
   <tr>
        <td align='center'>BARAKO 2</td>    
        <td align='center'>RED</td>
        <td align='center'>100</td>
        <td align='center'>100</td>
        <td align='center'>
        <select class='new' name='brand_new[]'>
            <option>Choose</option>
            <option value='brand_new'>Brand New</option>
            <option value='repo'>Repo</option>
       </select> 
        </td>
          <td> 
          <div id='repo' class='search_item' id='search_item' style='display:none'>    
          <input type='text' name='account_no' required></div>
       </td>
       </tr>
         <tr>
            <td align='center'>BARAKO 2</td>    
            <td align='center'>RED</td>
            <td align='center'>200</td>
            <td align='center'>200</td>
            <td align='center'>
            <select class='new' name='brand_new[]'>
                 <option>Choose</option>
                 <option value='brand_new'>Brand New</option>
                 <option value='repo'>Repo</option>
            </select> 
            </td>
            <td> 
            <div id='repo' class='search_item' id='search_item' style='display:none'>    
            <input type='text' name='account_no' required></div>
            </td>   
             </tr>
             <tr>
              <td align='center'>BARAKO 2</td>  
                <td align='center'>RED</td>
                <td align='center'>300</td>
                <td align='center'>300</td>
                <td align='center'>
                <select class='new' name='brand_new[]'>
                   <option>Choose</option>
                   <option value='brand_new'>Brand New</option>
                   <option value='repo'>Repo</option>
                </select> 
               </td>
                  <td> 
                    <div id='repo' class='search_item' id='search_item' style='display:none'>    
                    <input type='text' name='account_no' required> 
                 </div>
                </td>  
               </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
```

My Problem is only the first row of data loop are working, and the rest are not.

Comment: OK, so what's not working?

Comment: You cannot do it like that, ID's have to be unique.

Comment: @NathanTuggy only the first row of data are working and the rest are not.

Comment: @jeroen what I need to do?

Comment: Use another way to address your elements, using classes, the parent container, etc. or make the ID's unique.

Comment: @jeroen do you have any example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things about `id`s:

1. An element can only have one `id`
2. An `id` can only be used once on a page

So this is invalid:

```
<div id='repo' class='search_item' id='search_item' style='display:none'>
```

All you have to use is a `class` (and FYI its better to add that `display:none` to a stylesheet rather than apply it inline but thats up tok you):

```
<div class='search_item' style='display:none'>
```

Once your HTML is set up better you can use the following JS:

```
// Search by dates function
var search = $('.new')

search.change(function() {
   var selected = $(this).val();
    if(selected == "repo"){
       $(this).closest("tr").find(".search_item").show(); 
    }else{
       $(this).closest("tr").find(".search_item").hide();
    }
    
});
```

You need to navigate to the right `.search_item` of `$(this)` which is the selected dropdown. To do this you can simply do:

```
$(this).closest("tr").find(".search_item").show();
```

You could also do:

```
$(this).parent().next().find(".search_item").show();
```

But if you were to ever add in another `td` in between the two or changed the markup it would throw off your script. By traversing backwards to the "closest" `tr` and then descending down to `.search_item` you can assure that this code will work regardless of extra markup being added.

## [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/176vehy2/)

Comment: Hi, thank you, last one thing. Can you add a validation every time the  user select the repo? it's like the field must not be emptied. thank you so much.

Comment: You could look for each `select` on submit and if "empty" add an error class like this: [http://jsfiddle.net/176vehy2/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/176vehy2/1/)

Comment: Hi, last thing, how about the `account no` field? there must be a validation also for `account no` field when repo is selected, again thanks a bunch man!